# If $a\equiv b \pmod{n}$ and the integers $a, b$, and $n$ are divisible by $d>0$ then $\frac{a}{d}\equiv\frac{b}{d} \pmod{\frac{n}{d}}$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

this is related to my homework right now, i just don't have someone to ask

> If $a\equiv b \pmod n$ and the integers $a, b$, and $n$ are divisible by $d>0$ then
> $$
> \frac{a}{d}\equiv\frac{b}{d} \pmod {n/d}
> $$

[original screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQL8y.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2059752/mod-distributive-law-factoring-bmod-ab-bmod-ac-ab-bmod-c)

Comment: Use `\pmod{x}` to get $\pmod{x}$.

Comment: @Darsen See Arturo's comment

Comment: Also If gcd(d,n}=1 you can write as a/d=c/dmod(n)

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:** $a \equiv b \pmod n$ means that there exists an integer $k$ for which $a - b = kn$.